# retrive data from mysql to android using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have created a page which shows data that is present in the Mysql DB. I have used PHP for connection. PHP file contains select query to show data present into the DB. PHP file is called by android code. after completing JSON parsing, the data should display on app. But the issue is data is not getting retrieved on app.

Here, There is not a single error I am getting in java code. Also, I executed php file localhost it works totally fine and in output, i am getting the JSON data.

The only thing is JSON is not retrieving on the app. Please help me. I'm badly stuck here. I tried whole day for this and I didn't find anything. I need help guys!!! Please if you find out anything, do let me know.

Code:

```
See_Issue.java (where data will retrive from DB)
package com.example.mi.mikpiadmin;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class See_Issue extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView listView;

    private String JSON_STRING;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.see_feedback);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view) ;
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getJSON();

    }


    private void showEmployee(){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ISSUE_ARRAY);

            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String storename = jo.getString(Config.TAG_STORE_NAME);
                String issue = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ISSUE);

                HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
                employees.put(Config.TAG_STORE_NAME,storename);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_ISSUE,issue);
                list.add(employees);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                See_Issue.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{Config.TAG_STORE_NAME,Config.TAG_DESCRIBE},
                new int[]{R.id.editTextstorename, R.id.editTextdescribe});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    private void getJSON(){
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

            private ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(See_Issue.this,"Fetching Data","Wait...",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                JSON_STRING = s;
                showEmployee();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                return rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ISSUE);
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, See_Issue.class);
        HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        String empId = map.get(Config.TAG_ISSUE_ID).toString();
        intent.putExtra(Config.EMP_ID,empId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}

Config.java
package com.example.mi.mikpiadmin;

public class Config {
    public static final String URL_GET_ALL = "http://10.238.4.166/new/one.php";
    public static final String URL_GET_ISSUE = "http://10.238.4.166/new/see_issue.php";
    //public static final String URL_GET_EMP = "http://10.238.4.166/new/getFeedback.php?id=";
    //Keys that will be used to send the request to php scripts
    public static final String KEY_EMP_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_EMP_STORE_NAME = "storename";
    public static final String KEY_EMP_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_EMP_FEEDBACK = "feedback";

    //JSON Tags
    public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_STORENAME = "storename";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    public static final String TAG_FEEDBACK = "feedback";

    //employee id to pass with intent
    public static final String EMP_ID = "emp_id";


    public static final String TAG_JSON_ISSUE_ARRAY="result";
    public static final String TAG_ISSUE_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_STORE_NAME = "storename";
    public static final String TAG_ISSUE = "issue";
    public static final String TAG_DESCRIBE = "describe";

}
```

getIssue.php

```
<?php 
    //Importing Database Script 
    require_once('dbConfig.php');

    //Creating sql query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_issue";

    //getting result 
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    //creating a blank array 
    $result = array();

    //looping through all the records fetched
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

        //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
        array_push($result,array(
            "id"=>$row['id'],
            "store_name"=>$row['store_name'],
            "issue"=>$row['issue'],
            "describe"=>$row['describ']

        ));
    }

    //Displaying the array in json format 
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);

RequestHandler.java
package com.example.mi.mikpiadmin;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class RequestHandler {

    //Method to send httpPostRequest
    //This method is taking two arguments
    //First argument is the URL of the script to which we will send the request
    //Other is an HashMap with name value pairs containing the data to be send with the request
    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
        //Creating a URL
        URL url;

        //StringBuilder object to store the message retrieved from the server
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            //Initializing Url
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            //Creating an httmlurl connection
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //Configuring connection properties
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //Creating an output stream
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            //Writing parameters to the request
            //We are using a method getPostDataString which is defined below
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String response;
                //Reading server response
                while ((response = br.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(response);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String sendGetRequest(String requestURL){
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestURL);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String s;
            while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(s+"\n");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String sendGetRequestParam(String requestURL, String id){
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestURL+id);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String s;
            while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(s+"\n");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check your php code have results? you need to go step by step.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a typo? `getIssue.php` !== `see_issue.php`

Comment: @jeroen: Sorry its a typing mistake

Comment: @PoorviGandhi: Yar, I have gone  crazy. I checked every possible thing. php file works just fine. I am getting data into my localhost

Comment: Please see the updated code. I have added request handler's code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is the RequestHandler returning something? I suggest to put a breakpoint on your `PostExecute` method to see what's response are you getting from the Backend.
Also I personally prefer to use OkHTTP (http://square.github.io/okhttp/), for a simple get request it will be something like this on your `doInBackground`:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url(Config.URL_GET_ISSUE)
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
return response.body().string();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to communicate between client side application and a remote database is by using RESTful API with it's famous HTTP requests GET, PUT, POST and DELETE. When you have a REST API you can have a multiple client side apps using the same database, like Android, IOS or JAVASCRIPT. And it will be secured by an API_KEY so only requests that are authorized to do the queries or modifications will be accepted. 
There are many ways to create an REST API since you are a PHP developer I would recommend [Slim PHP framework](https://www.slimframework.com/) since it's lightweight and easy to use.
Another benefit from using frameworks is security and sql injection problems that comes a lot when beginners code PHP from scratch.